# Combine Input stream

Tags: dart

I have two inputs element and want to listen `KeyUp` event on it.

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

What I want to reach is, when both inputs is not empty, then the submit should be enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  final ids = ['username', 'password'];
  final inputs = ids.map((id) => document.getElementById(id) as InputElement);
  inputs.forEach((input) {
    input.onKeyUp.listen((e) {
      final SubmitButtonInputElement submit =
          document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
      submit.disabled = inputs.any((input) => input.value.isEmpty);
    });
  });
}
```

Test on DartPad : https://dartpad.dartlang.org/49e61d036983e37a0d02663674d04b83

Comment: First off all, thanks to much.  Is `{` after `(input)` a callback function or is a lambda expression?

Comment: `(input){ ... }` is a lambda that is applied to all the `inputs`.